# Can not change tabular model cube from IN-MEMORY to DIRECTQUERY

Tags: olap-cube

I have a tabular Cube deployed on server with IN-MEMORY. When i tried to change it to DIRECTQUERY mode i am getting error.

"Row Level Security is not supported in a database with DirectQuery property.
An error occurred when loading the DimensionPermission.
 (Microsoft.AnalysisServices) "

I have connected cube by SSMS and changing to DirectQuery by Right Click on Cube -> Properties.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Regards

Rajnish

Answer (score 0):

Which SSAS version are you using. If you are using SSAS 2014 or lower version, Row Level Security is not supported in a database with DirectQuery Model.

DirectQuery can be used if there is no column with calculation in tabular Model Cube.

If you are using SSAS 2016 or higher version, then you might need to check the restrictions for a database with DirectQuery model. See restrictions in below document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/directquery-mode-ssas-tabular